# Three-way hex driver that I can lock to something?

Tags: maintenance, tools

*I know this looks like I'm asking for a product recommendation, but if there's an answer it is unambiguous and non-obvious, so I think it fits within the spirit of SE.*

I want to chain up a [three-way hex driver](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=3-way%20hex%20driver&t=osx&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images) to a bike rack at the back of our building, for quick access for adjusting seats and such. But none I've found have a hole in the middle that would allow this. Does anyone know of a make that does?

(I specifically want a three-way design because it's simple and robust; this will sit out in the elements. I don't think a multitool-style folding bike tool will last. But I'm happy to hear of any other styles you think might fit these requirements.)

Comment: Rather than leaving the tool in the elements, consider making a shelf + lid/cover that puts them out of the rain.   Something as simple as cutting a hole in a plastic bottle so the hole  faces away from prevailing wind/rain will help.

Answer (score 7):

Showing how Park Tools does it for inspiration - not a product recommendation.

[image]

They have a bicycle workstation product. It's very expensive and I think it can be built for much less money.

Focusing on the question - look at the hex driver that comes with the workstation.

[image]

They have a weather resistant hex multi tool and they drilled a hole in it.

If you bought a multi tool like that and just ran a cable through the middle you wouldn't even need a hole.

So, a stainless-steel hex multi tool with a stainless-steel cable run through the tool attached to your bike rack.

Something like:
[image]
or
[image]

Answer (score 7):

The suggestions already posted are good ones, e.g. I like the idea of drilling a hole through one of the plastic-sided Park style folding tools.

But if you're really set on the three-way tool, I'm wondering if the following would work.

[image]

Here, the red line coming in from the lower right would be some wrapped steel cable as is usually used for locking stuff up in these situations. If you follow it, it goes over prong A, under B, over C, then hops *over* the main incoming cable (yellow part), then under A, wraps around and comes back over A, and then gets crimped onto the original cable (green dor) after pulling all the over/under parts in tight towards the hub.

If the crimped part can't slide to allow more slack in, I think this works?!?

I did a quick mock-up with a paper cutout shaped like a Park tool and some dental floss knotted at the crimp point, and it seems to work. You can slide the crimp point around a bit, so it kind of slowly circles the hub, but it seems like the over/under combos prevent you untangling the cable run around the hub and getting it off, all assuming you can't slide the crimped point to pull in more slack. If anyone can see how to unwrap this without breaking or sliding the crimp point, I'd be curious to know.

Comment: OP needs like eight feet of chain otherwise it's a pita to use. So use **Lamp Chain**, which you can **open the links with pliers, put some links to capture it as shown**, then link it to some chain. +1

Comment: I was picturing what I drew being done with thin steel cable and crimps, similar to the Park tool set in David D's post. Where is the 8 feet of chain coming from? I don't see anything about that in the OP. Having said that, yes if someone preferring to use chain, it's possible a large chain link could be opened up and coaxed around hub of the tool in a similar manner.

Answer (score 6):

If you cannot find a three-way hex driver with a hole in it, the obvious solution is to drill a hole in it. Now it would have to be robust to do so. The older Park versions had a center hub made of a block of aluminum which would work brilliantly, but alas, they do not make them that way anymore.

This is the older Park design:

[image]

Another option would be individual wrenches that have a robust loop in the handle that can have a flexible cable or slender chain run through the holes. These may not be cheap, but a knock-off brand may possibly be found at a wholesale tool outlet:

[image]

Comment: What’s this style called?

Comment: @RobertAtkins, if you are referring to the last image, I believe they are called "T-handle" or similar.  Not all of these would even have a hole in the handle.  I just noticed this one in an image search and thought it may fit your needs as an option.

Comment: Aha. Much easier to find with the hole through the handle, I think this might be the best solution to my problem.

Comment: @RobertAtkins I hope it works for you. A lot of good ideas and experiences to tap at this site.